# NextJS/Django Manually Typing in URLs

Tags: reactjs, django, url, routes, next.js

I'm trying to set up an application that uses Django on the backend and NextJS on the front end.

I've set this up by statically exporting the NextJS app then Django app handles routing and uses `index.html` as a catch all for any routes it does not know.

This is working relatively well however I am running into a routing issue with NextJS and I'm not sure where exactly it's coming from. While my client side routing works fine (i.e,. `Link` components work as expected) it does nothing if I do this by typing in the URL.

My directory structure is like this:

```
...
- pages
     - _app.tsx
     - index.tsx
     - login.tsx
...
```

Therefore I should expect `/login` to route to the login page and again this works as expected in the `Link` tag however when I manually type in `localhost:8000/login/` it just redirects to `index.tsx`.

Some other potentially relevant files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        loader: "akamai",
        path: "/",
    },
}
```

I have a feeling it's because the files are client side rendered not server side but I've not seen anything to suggest this is an unavoidable side effect of that. To that end I've tried utilizing `exportPathMap`, `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` but none seem to work as expected. I even tried the `redirects` property but nothing.

I really am stumped why this isn't working and I can't really find any info on it - again it does lead me to believe this is just how NextJS works for CSR but I really can't believe that's the case.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: django routing info below:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [
    # APIS =============================== #
    path("api/", include("api.urls")),
    # ADMIN ============================== #
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # NEXTJS ============================= #
    re_path('^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

**views.py**

```
front_end_view = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")
```

My front end is in a `client` folder and I have `client/out` listed as a staticfiles_dir.

Comment: how did u set up routing in django?

Comment: @Yilmaz added that info - just sends everything to the front end. Not thrilled about this method but it seems to work well enough.

Will have some SEO issues later so trying to figure out a 'hybrid' SSR/Django thing but that's a problem for another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't fully figured this out but after much more investigation the issue does seem to be on the NextJS side rather than Django.

The 'real' solution is to start using NextJS via the `next start` command rather than static export. Again based off the docs I don't feel like this is the case but after switching to that and getting it to work with Django everyhting works as expected.

That said, it's not always possible to do that so if you must use static export I added the following to my `pages/_app.tsx` to get the URLs functional:

```
const router = useRouter()
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        // get pathname and location
        let pathname = router.pathname
        let location = window.location.pathname

        // ensure paths have trailing '/'
        const lastLocation = location.charAt(location.length - 1);
        if (lastLocation != '/') {
            location = `${location}/`
        }
        const lastPath = pathname.charAt(pathname.length - 1);
        if (lastPath != '/') {
            pathname = `${pathname}/`
        }

        // redirect to page in actual url
        if (pathname != location) {
            router.replace(location).then((success) => {
                if (!success) {
                    const newPath = '/404'
                    window.location.pathname = newPath
                    let res = router.replace(newPath)
                }
            })
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})
```

You also need to `trailingSlash: true,` in your `next.config.js`.

Can't say I'm a fan of this 'hack' but it seems to be working as expected but I can't imagine this is the 'most correct' answer. This does however fully fix manually typing in URLs as well as any other CSR routing i.e., `a` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is too late to answer this question, but I hope it will come in handy for those, who want to save time. The actual problem is that Next.js by default does not support closing slashes, but django's default configuration is the opposite. So we face a multiple redirections error in a browser, that is pretty logical. To solve this problem, you can either set "trailingSlash: true" in  next.config.js file or set "APPEND_SLASH:False" in django's settings.py. It must solve the problem. P.S. It's better to set a closing slash in nextjs, so that you don't need to manually change all the urls in your backend application.